# exec command in php not working

Tags: php, r, exec

I have an R script that I need to execute on my PHP page. Here's my code

```
exec("Rscript D:/webs/popdyn/SingleSpeciesLWR_2.r D:/webs/popdyn/hello.csv none");
```

I have 2 parameters here, 1st is my csv file and 2nd is none. It works well when I execute this in cmd, but in PHP it doesn't work.

Comment: Give the full path to `Rscript`. PHP may not find it in its own PATH environment.

Comment: Do they need to be backslashes to work properly, perhaps?  `D:\webs\popdyn....`

Comment: Check permissions and `Rscript` in PATH

Comment: Thanks guys, what I did is I gave the full path of Rscript.

Comment: For some reason, on my local computer it is working fine. And then I tried the same setup with other computer, but php didn't execute the R script.

Comment: Could be that rscript is in a different place, permissions are stronger/restricted out that exec is restricted. First thing to check, Can you run anything through exec at all?

Comment: Well for some reason, one of my library isn't working. What I did is that I re-install all of them and then restart the system. I saw the error when I use system() instead of exec(). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a PATH issue. Check that Rscript.exe is in the PATH for your system environment, and not your local user environment.

Reason: When PHP runs exec, it run is the environment of the user of the loading application (Could be IIS, Apache or PHP, depending on your set up). You can find out which user and add the path to that user, or just add the path to the system environment.  You can do this through the control panel (NOT command line - adds to local only!).

Alternatively, specify the full path to Rscript in the exec().

Comment: For some reason, on my local computer it is working fine. And then I tried the same setup with other computer, but php didn't execute the R script.